# Why do different users get different IP via the same interface

Tags: linux, routing, iptables, network-interface

On the same server, on root, I am getting the **correct** internet ip of the interface

```
root@server:~# curl -s --interface ppp0 ipcheck.com
111.111.111.111root@server:~#
```

However...

If it's not super user, I get the ip of the default route/interface eth0 or eth1 internet ip instead of ppp0's internet ip and that is not what i expect.

```
matrix@server:~$ curl -s --interface ppp0 ipcheck.com
222.222.222.222matrix@server:~$
```

My question is why do different users get different IP/Route? It's the same application, same interface which i have set the route correctly...

In /etc/iproute2/rt_tables, I have added

```
    20      isp1
    30      isp2
    40      ppp0
    50      ppp1
    60      ppp2
```

ip route's first 3 lines:

```
    default 
        nexthop via 222.222.222.1  dev eth0 weight 1
        nexthop via 222.222.222.2  dev eth1 weight 1
10.200.20.1 dev ppp0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.200.21.4
10.200.20.1 dev ppp1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.200.21.9 
10.200.20.1 dev ppp2  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.200.21.7
```

ip rule:

```
0:  from all lookup local 
32761:  from all fwmark 0x60 lookup ppp2 
32762:  from all fwmark 0x50 lookup ppp1
32763:  from all fwmark 0x40 lookup ppp0 
32764:  from all fwmark 0x30 lookup ISP2 
32765:  from all fwmark 0x20 lookup ISP1 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

iptables:

```
    -A PREROUTING -t mangle -i eth0 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -d 222.222.222.222 -j CONNMARK --set-mark 0x20
    -A PREROUTING -t mangle -i eth1 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -d 222.222.222.223 -j CONNMARK --set-mark 0x30
    -A PREROUTING -t mangle -i br0 -m connmark --mark 0x20 -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
    -A PREROUTING -t mangle -i br0 -m connmark --mark 0x30 -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
    -A OUTPUT -t mangle -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
-A PREROUTING -t mangle -i ppp0 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -d 10.200.21.4 -j CONNMARK --set-mark 0x40
-A PREROUTING -t mangle -i br0 -m connmark --mark 0x40 -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
-A PREROUTING -t mangle -i ppp1 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -d 10.200.21.9 -j CONNMARK --set-mark 0x50
-A PREROUTING -t mangle -i br0 -m connmark --mark 0x50 -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
-A PREROUTING -t mangle -i ppp2 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -d 10.200.21.7 -j CONNMARK --set-mark 0x60
-A PREROUTING -t mangle -i br0 -m connmark --mark 0x60 -j CONNMARK --restore-mark

-A OUTPUT -t mangle -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j CONNMARK --restore-mark


    -A POSTROUTING -t nat -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
    -A POSTROUTING -t nat -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
    -A POSTROUTING -t nat -o ppp+ -j MASQUERADE

    -A FORWARD -i br0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -i br0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -i br0 -o ppp+ -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -m state -i eth0 -o br0 --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -m state -i eth1 -o br0 --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -m state -i ppp+ -o br0 --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -i br0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: It would help if you can tell us something about the IP addresses returned, but (without having enough for an answer) my first guess would be that binding to a specific interface requires a level of access that the ordinary user account doesn't have, but root does have.

Comment: I am a bit surprised: I do not have a ppp server to connect to, but with OpenVPN, using the virtual interface `tun0` to play the same game, the returned IP addresses are identical.

Comment: I cannot find any documentation about it, but afair as user, you cannot set the interface.

Comment: Please provide the output of `ip route` and `iptables-save`

Comment: If either output is wrong, tell us which one and why. If neither output is wrong, tell us what the actual issue is.

Comment: As you can see, I did not set any iptables rules based on any specific user. So why i am getting the main ip/outgoing address instead when curl via any ppp interface with a non super user?